# Regressing one seasonal series on another: should I include seasonal dummies?

Tags: regression, time-series, seasonality

When exactly do I have to adjust for seasonality?

Suppose I have a **simple linear regression model** with just **one independent variable**. The independent variable exhibits some sort of seasonal pattern, which in turn (obviously) effects the dependent variable.

Would I have to use (for example) dummy variables in this case?

I think an illustrative example for what I am trying to ask are electricity prices. You could just put up a regression model which uses electricity prices as the dependent variable and load as the independent variable (this is very simple but suffices in this context). The prices show a seasonal pattern, but this is **only** the case because the load shows a seasonal pattern.

I do not get why I should include dummy variables for e.g. each season of the year, when this effect is basically included in the independent variable.

Am I missing something? I appreciate any helpful comment/answer.

Comment: What do you want to do with the model? Describe the data, test some economic theory, forecast, ...? Whether you need the dummies depends in part on that.

Comment: I want to describe the data.